# no exception when adding false type in list

Tags: java, generics

i found a (for my state of knowledge) strange behavior during the adding of a Class type to a list.

I have a list which holds all implementing classes of an Abstract class `List<Class<MyAbstractClass>> myImplementations`. I added a type of a non-derived class and there was no error. Can anyone explain why i can do something like `myImplementations.add(SomeOtherClass.class);` without any exception? It seems that the second generic type (MyAbstractClass) has no effect at all.

--- edit ---

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass{
  public static String getMyIdentification(){ throw new RuntimeException("implement method");}
}

public class MyImplementation extends MyAbstractClass{
  public static String getMyIdentification(){ return "SomeUUID";}
}

public class OtherClass{}

// in another class:
List<Class<MyAbstractClass>> myImplementations = new ArrayList<Class<MyAbstractClass>>();
myImplementations.add(MyImplementation.class); // does not cause any error
myImplementations.add(OtherClass.class); // does not cause any error, but should in my opinion??
```

---- edit end ---

Thank you,
el

Comment: can you please post your code.

Comment: The given code is engough to construct the problem. You just have to initialize the List 'myImplementations'.

Comment: @elCapitano it isn't - see my answer.

Comment: @Bozho: for the problem, the code is enough - for the solution not :-)

Comment: @elCapitano - it is not enough. You can see from the answers that we have to guess what could have caused your problem.

Comment: Ok, the Problem seems to be more complex than i thought. You are right, i will post more code

Comment: No, using eclipse... and it seems that the default settings of eclipse force to give warnings due to generics... damn!

You both (Bozho & Anreas_D) helped me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type is erased during compilation, so you won't see any exception at runtime. The compiler should complain in your case or give a warning.

```
List<Class<String>> list = new ArrayList<Class<String>>();
list.add(Integer.class);                      // should create a compiletime error
list.add(Class.forName("java.lang.Integer")); // should create a warning
                                              // and run due to type erasure
```

---

The type parameter `Class<String>` is erased during compilation - it is only used by the compiler to check if the java source code is valid. The compiled bytecode doesn't contain this information anymore, on byte code level the list will hold and accept `Object` or any subclass of `Object`. And because `Integer.class` is a subclass of `Object`, the code will run - until the runtime throws ClassCastExceptions at the programmer, just because it expected `Class<String>` instances.

Answer (score 1):

This behaves as expected, using eclipse compiler:

```
List<Class<? extends CharSequence>> myImplementations = 
    new ArrayList<Class<? extends CharSequence>>();
myImplementations.add(String.class);
myImplementations.add(Vector.class);
```

i.e. the compiler complains only for the second add. If it passes compilation, however, the list is transformed into a raw list, and you won't get an exception until you get elements out of the list - using the foreach loop, for example.

without the `? extends` the compilation fails even for `String`. And that's how it should be. I'm surprised that you don't have any errors, since java generics are invariant - i.e. you cannot add a `Subclass` instance to a `List<Superclass>`.

Comment: yep! this is a solution for me, but does not explain why the second type has no effect. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I suspect he has turned off those "pesky" unsafe conversion, etc warning messages.

Comment: "don't touch the defaults unless you know what you are doing" is a very sensible policy :)

Answer (score 0):

#### On type erasure

Java's generics are non-reified. A `List<String>` and a `List<Integer>` are different types at compile time, but both types are erased to simply `List` at run-time. This means that by circumventing the compile-time checks, you can insert an `Integer` into `List<String>` at run-time, which by itself may not generate `ClassCastException`. Here's an example:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
List raw = names; // generates compiler warning about raw type!

raw.add((Integer) 42); // does not throw ClassCastException! (yet!)

// but here comes trouble!
for (String s : names) {
    // Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
    //    java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
}
```

Note that you'd have to *deliberately* circumvent the compile-time check to violate the generic type invariant: the compiler will do its best to ensure that `List<String>` will indeed contain only `String`, and will generate as many warnings and errors as necessary to enforce this.

---

#### On checked collections

Sometimes we want to enforce the type safety at run-time. For most scenarios, the checked collection wrappers from [`java.util.Collections`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) can facilitate this behavior. From the documentation:

> [`<E> Collection<E> checkedCollection(Collection<E> c, Class<E> type)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#checkedCollection%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Class%29)
>
> Returns a *dynamically typesafe view* of the specified collection. *Any attempt to insert an element of the wrong type will result in an immediate* `ClassCastException`. Assuming a collection contains no incorrectly typed elements prior to the time a dynamically typesafe view is generated, and that all subsequent access to the collection takes place through the view, it is guaranteed that the collection cannot contain an incorrectly typed element.
>
> The generics mechanism in the language provides compile-time (static) type checking, but *it is possible to defeat this mechanism with unchecked casts*. Usually this is not a problem, as the compiler issues warnings on all such unchecked operations. There are, however, times when static type checking alone is not sufficient. For example, suppose a collection is passed to a third-party library and it is imperative that the library code not corrupt the collection by inserting an element of the wrong type.
>
> Another use of dynamically typesafe views is debugging. Suppose a program fails with a `ClassCastException`, indicating that an incorrectly typed element was put into a parameterized collection. Unfortunately, the exception can occur at any time after the erroneous element is inserted, so it typically provides little or no information as to the real source of the problem. If the problem is reproducible, one can quickly determine its source by temporarily modifying the program to wrap the collection with a dynamically typesafe view. For example, this declaration:
>
> ```
>     Collection<String> c = new HashSet<String>();
> ```
>
> may be replaced temporarily by this one:
>
> ```
>     Collection<String> c = Collections.checkedCollection(
>          new HashSet<String>(), String.class);
> ```
>
> Running the program again will cause it to fail at the point where an incorrectly typed element is inserted into the collection, clearly identifying the source of the problem.

Here's a modification of the previous snippet:

```
List<String> names = Collections.checkedList(
    new ArrayList<String>(), String.class
);
List raw = names; // generates compiler warning about raw type!

raw.add((Integer) 42); // throws ClassCastException!
// Attempt to insert class java.lang.Integer element into collection
// with element type class java.lang.String
```

Note that as a "bonus", a `Collections.checkedList` will throw `NullPointerException` at run-time on an attempt to `add(null)`.

---

#### On `Class.isAssignableFrom`

Unfortunately the behavior we want in this scenario is not supported by a `Collections.checkedList`: you can use it to ensure that only `java.lang.Class` instances can be added at run-time, but it will not ensure that the given `Class` object is a subclass of another `Class`.

Fortunately the [`Class.isAssignableFrom(Class)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) method allows you to make this check, but you'd have to write your own checked `List` wrapper to enforce this. The idea is illustrated here in a `static` helper method instead of a full `List` implementation:

```
static void add(List<Class<?>> list, Class<?> base, Class<?> child) {
    if (base.isAssignableFrom(child)) {
        list.add(child);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            String.format("%s is not assignable from %s",
                base.getName(),
                child.getName()
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Now we have:

```
List<Class<?>> list = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();

add(list, CharSequence.class, String.class);         // OK!
add(list, CharSequence.class, StringBuffer.class);   // OK!
add(list, CharSequence.class, StringBuilder.class);  // OK!

add(list, CharSequence.class, Integer.class);        // NOT OK!
// throws IllegalArgumentException:
// java.lang.CharSequence is not assignable from java.lang.Integer
```